# Is there a word for 1/3?

Tags: word-choice

So I know that in Mandarin, 1/2 is 二分之一 or 一半. Is there a similar word to 一半 for 1/3? I mean, instead of 三分之一, something like 一——？

Comment: there is 刻 for quarter hour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

因為十進制在中國已被使用了很長的時間，故比較少分數字詞；其中只有「半」作為單字詞，於中國古代應用如下。
Because the decimal system has been used for a long time in China, there are fewer fractional words.
半 is the only single word, which was used as follows in ancient China.

1/2 one-half 半、中半
1/3 one-third 少半、小半
2/3 two-thirds 太半、大半
1/4 one-fourth, a quarter 弱半
3/4 three-fourths, three quarters 強半

中國數字分數系統中，稱呼分數時，先稱呼分母，後稱呼分子。
In Chinese fractional system, the denominator is addressed first, and then the numerator.

例如：其亡者三二 (Two-thirds people died)。

Source: [中文數字](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%95%B8%E5%AD%97)

Answer (score 2):

三分之一 can only be shortened to 三分一.

The only way to avoid saying 三分一 is using smaller measuring unit. For example: 二十分鐘 instead of 三分一小時; 四分 instead of 三分一尺.

Similarly, 一半 can only be shortened to 半, as in 半小時 (三十分鐘), or 半尺 (六分)

Side note:

*1/4 hour (a quarter of an hour) can be translated to 一刻鐘 or 一刻 instead of 四分一小時 in Chinese.*

*1/4 hour (a quarter of an hour) can be transliterated to 一個骨 in Cantonese; 3/4 hour* (three quarters of an hour) = 三個骨

Answer (score 0):

Some patterns:

```
      English               Strictly in Mandarin(Cantonese in written)
1/3   one third               三(3)分之一(1)  
1/4   one fourth(quarter)     四(4)分之一(1)
2/5   two fifths              五(5)分之二(2)
```

See the pattern? Even in written 三分之一, It's common to write "3分之1". Since in Chinese, the number itself doesn't have the plural form, you can ignore the annoying"-s" or"-es".

In accounting, since 一，二，三...etc. The number itself are easily to be modified, so we might use “壹，贰，叁，肆...”, but that's another sotry.

Advanced patterns when it comes to 1(1/3) cases:

```
        English                     Strictly in Mandarin(Cantonese in written)
1+2/3   one and two thirds              一(1)又三(3)分之2(1)  
3+1/4   three and one fourth(quarter)   三(3)又四(4)分之一(1)
4+2/5   four and two fifths             四(4)又五(5)分之二(2)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

一比三，三分一，三分之一，一除三： all work!! but of course, is there a half word in English for 1/3? No, there isn't.

Comment: Shouldn't 一比三 and 一除三 actually mean a _ratio_ of 1:3, in other words 1/4? Using 一比三 to mean 1/3 (1:2) seems extremely weird to me...